# How do you filter data flow in azure synapse?

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I have created a dataflow using row_number and I want to extract only the values where row_number = 1, but I can't get it to work. Please tell me how to do this.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOW4n.png)

#azure #synapse #dataflow

Comment: can you provide some more information regarding this??

Comment: It was created with reference to this page.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/419209/additional-column-that-records-the-row-number-auto.html

I want to extract values with column row_number = 1 only.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to extract only the values where row_number = 1

**To filter rows based on column value we have two ways:**

1. Filter
2. Conditional split

**My Sample data after windows transformation**

[image]

> **Filter transformation**

In **Filter settings** give `Filter on` as **column name with particular value.**
Here I provided `RowNumber == 1`  so it will only filter rows where RowNumber =1.

[image]

**Output of Filter transformation**

[image]

> **Conditional split**

In **Conditional split settings** give `Split condition` as **column name with particular value.**
Here I provided `RowNumber == 1`  so it will only filter rows where RowNumber =1.
[image]

**Output of Conditional split transformation**

[image]